# SVN not updating recursively

Tags: svn, recursion, non-recursive

A few weeks ago, I checked out our whole SVN repo in `--non-recursive` mode.
Now it seems that when I do a `svn up`, it does not update the folder recursively.

It's a problem because I'd like to get the changes from my colleagues without having to go through each directory and do a `svn up` manually...

How can I force the update to be recursive ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

on next svn update command provide the parameter **--depth**:

```
svn up --depth infinity
```

on checking out a non-recursive checkout, subversion remembers this setting until you tell it otherwise.

Note: you should not use the parameter **-N** anymore as it is deprecated. Try to use **--depth files** or **--depth immediates**

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  The svn up --set-depth infinity is the one what worked for me.

Answer (score 21):

Following should work (with svn 1.7.x or later versions):

```
svn up --set-depth infinity
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the command bellow to execute **update** in all your trunk folders.

```
find <YOUR_ROOT_DIR> -type d -name trunk -exec svn up {} +
```

This is particularly useful, if were made many "**svn checkouts**" inside a root structure, as below.

- root

  - projectA

    - trunk
  - projectB

    - trunk
  - projectC

    - trunk

*In this cases, someone did checkout 3 times, one for each project.*