# SVN won't recursively update certain directories. Anyone know why?

Tags: svn

Here's my brain teaser of the day, and I appreciate your help figuring it out.

I was pulling down my team's changes for the day from subversion and I noticed it added a new tag for the project I'm working on, however just the root directory of the tag and no files.

```
$ svn update
Updating '.':
A    tags/release-103
```

Note it didn't add any files under the tag. Confused, my first thought was someone had botched their add, so I checked the directory on the repository:

```
$ svn ls tags/release-103
dev-package.sh
devapache-install.sh
install.txt
manage.py
project/
publish.txt
server-install-8000.sh
server-install.sh
server-stage.sh
source/
static/
subscribe/
task_mgr.py
templates/
```

Everything looks good on the server. Maybe there is something wrong with my copy?

```
$ rm -r tags/release-103
$ svn update -r3708
Updating '.':
A    tags/release-103
```

Experimenting...

```
$ svn update tags/release-103/project
A    tags/release-103/project
A    tags/release-103/project/celery.py
A    tags/release-103/project/settings.py.default
A    tags/release-103/project/formats
A    tags/release-103/project/formats/en
A    tags/release-103/project/formats/en/formats.py
A    tags/release-103/project/formats/en/__init__.py
A    tags/release-103/project/formats/__init__.py
A    tags/release-103/project/urls.py
A    tags/release-103/project/wsgi.py
A    tags/release-103/project/middleware.py
A    tags/release-103/project/__init__.py
A    tags/release-103/project/settings.py.devapache
```

WTF ... So if I specify anything below the tag, it will download it perfectly, but it won't update recursively at the root tag.

I've also tried rolling back and rolling forward the revision # and forcing the update. Nothing has worked so far.

Anyone have an idea of what's happening? Appreciate you sharing your brain power on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't been using the keyword "recursive" in my google foo, and after writing this I tried it and found this: 
[SVN not updating recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9281163/svn-not-updating-recursively)

This worked:

```
 svn up --set-depth infinity
```

This did not work:

```
 svn up --depth infinity
```